# Dereferencing pointer elements in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm a complete noob at coding and I'm just having some issue dereferencing pointer data.

```
int* array[4] = {E2020, E2024, E2028, E2032};
cout << (*array[0]) << endl;
```

If i need to dereference an element that's a pointer pointing to its value(let say in this example E2020 has value of 10), how would I express that in code?

My understanding is that since array is already a pointer, I just need to use the dereferencing sign(*) once. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Can you show how `E020` and the like are declared?

Comment: If as you say `E2020` has the value `10` then `array[0]` is a pointer and `*array[0]` is the value at address `10`; see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence  (On non-embedded platforms be prepared for this to segfault.)

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer (without guessing) given only the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is an array of pointers to integers. Assuming the addresses in array elements are correct, your code makes perfect sense. You are indexing into the array to access first element `array[0]`, then dereferencing it to access the integer stored at that location `(*array[0])`.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to know how I would dereference elements that are pointers